# Regex to exactly match against a given set of keywords in between delimiters?

Tags: java, regex

Im trying a regex to exactly match against a given set of keywords in between delimiters?

For example:

Keywords: keyone, keytwo, keythree
Start delimiter: ;
End delimiter: ;

Text under test: some text ;keyone; other text  ;keytwo; some text  ;keythreeeee;

Regex i tried : ;([keyonekeytwokeythree]+);

Problem with this regex is, this matching with keythreeeee also. My expectation is it should not match keythreeeee because this is not exact match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read up on regular expression syntax.

```
([keyonekeytwokeythree]+)
```

The square bracket syntax tells the regexp matcher to match 'any number of characters from the set `keyonekeytwokeythree`'. It will thus also match `yekenoeerth`.

You're looking for something like:

```
;(keyone|keytwo|keythree);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a regex like this:

```
;(keyone|keytwo|keythree);
```

Answer (score 0):

I first take all the text inside delimiters.

```
     (delmiterSart)(.)*(delimiterEnd)
```

and then on this selected text i try to search you word

```
     (key1|key2|keyn)+
```